# Debugging a ARM Cortex-M Hard Fault for IAR Assembly

Tags: assembly, arm, inline-assembly, iar

The following code written for GCC
I want to know how make this code to be compiled under IAR compiler

```
Default_Handler:
  /* Load the address of the interrupt control register into r3. */
  ldr r3, NVIC_INT_CTRL_CONST
  /* Load the value of the interrupt control register into r2 from the
  address held in r3. */
  ldr r2, [r3, #0]
  /* The interrupt number is in the least significant byte - clear all
  other bits. */
  uxtb r2, r2
Infinite_Loop:
  /* Now sit in an infinite loop - the number of the executing interrupt
  is held in r2. */
  b  Infinite_Loop
  .size  Default_Handler, .-Default_Handler

.align 4
/* The address of the NVIC interrupt control register. */
NVIC_INT_CTRL_CONST: .word 0xe000ed04


/* The prototype shows it is a naked function - in effect this is just an
assembly function. */
static void HardFault_Handler( void ) __attribute__( ( naked ) );

/* The fault handler implementation calls a function called
prvGetRegistersFromStack(). */
static void HardFault_Handler(void)
{
    __asm volatile
    (
        " tst lr, #4                                                \n"
        " ite eq                                                    \n"
        " mrseq r0, msp                                             \n"
        " mrsne r0, psp                                             \n"
        " ldr r1, [r0, #24]                                         \n"
        " ldr r2, handler2_address_const                            \n"
        " bx r2                                                     \n"
        " handler2_address_const: .word prvGetRegistersFromStack    \n"
    );
}
```

I'm sure there simple syntax changes to make it compile

Comment: Why mess around with inline-assebly? Isn't it better to implement this as real assembler function instead?

Comment: I want to implement it with inline assembly, because HardFault_Handler run in C file.

Comment: How about moving the code to an assembly file instead? Most of the stuff in the C-file is used to prevent the compiler from interpreting the source as C-code anyway.

Comment: Looks like you forgot `__attribute__(( naked ));` on the function definition, and only have it on the prototype.  Are you sure that works for GCC?  Check the disassembly for compiler-generated instructions before/after your block.

Answer (score 0):

I have figured it my self, here is the solution:

```
 __asm volatile
        (
            " tst lr, #4                                                \n"
            " ite eq                                                    \n"
            " mrseq r0, msp                                             \n"
            " mrsne r0, psp                                             \n"
            " ldr r1, [r0, #24]                                         \n"
            " ldr r2, =prvGetRegistersFromStack                         \n"
            " bx r2                                                     \n"
        );
```